# Rails sending Parameters: {} instead of Parameters: {"action" => "index" "controller" => "index"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

To make my rails website work, even when the Database in down. in the  `def rescue_action_in_public(exception)` 
function i catch the Mysql:Error exception and render a page, which doest have any database reference ,like

```
    def rescue_action_in_public(exception)
    when  Mysql::Error, Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Timeout::Error 
   puts "-----the controller name #{controller_name}"
     if controller_name == "index"
                render :template => 'index/index'
     end
```

this works perfectly, when i start the app, and stop the DB immediately and try access my pages.

but if i start the app, browse few pages and then stop the DB. and now try to access the pages, i could see empty parameter in the logs like

```
Parameters: {}
```

instead of

```
Parameters: {"action" => "index" "controller" => "index"}
```

as a result this condition

```
if controller_name == "index"
```

is not being met.

I dont know, why proper controller name is not set in this senario.
or if its something to do with the routes.rb file.

Comment: Which version of Rails is this happening with?

Comment: the rails version is 2.1

Comment: can you add exception to the log ? I'm curious if it happens with always the same exception

Comment: i think, its happening only with Mysql:Error exception. u mean, shall i introduce someother exception and see its happening like this?

Comment: and consistently, Parameters: {"action" => "index" "controller" => "index"} comes  after every 5 Parameters: {} .. (so if i keep refreshing the page, expected behaviour comes after every 5 request.)and this corelate with the number of servers in my rails app which is 5.

Comment: Does it happen in production only? or both production and development?

Answer (score 1):

i had to add this line

```
@controller = Routing::Routes.recognize(@request)
```

to the

```
def failsafe_rescue(exception)
```

in the action_controller/dispatcher.rb file

```
def failsafe_rescue(exception)
        @controller = Routing::Routes.recognize(@request) //added line
        self.class.failsafe_response(@output, '500 Internal Server Error', exception) do
          if @controller ||= defined?(::ApplicationController) ? ::ApplicationController : Base
            @controller.process_with_exception(@request, @response, exception).out(@output)
          else
            raise exception
          end
        end
      end
```

so the reason for this is. when MYSQL:ERROR exception happens, in

```
 def dispatch
```

method, the control goes to the failsafe_rescue and not the method

```
 def handle_request
```

which has the

```
@controller = Routing::Routes.recognize(@request)
```

statement. 
as a result, routes is not added to the request object.